# How to configure the Code coverage for funtional tests outside the Application build

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

We are trying to set up `Code Coverage tool` for our `product/Desktop Based` Application to get the Code Coverage report for our `Automation Scripts(Functional Tests).`

I have not done code coverage Integration before hence I am not able to get straight approach for this.

Please see the following requirement and let me know your inputs.

1. Firstly Out automation scripts are Functional  based `tests(UI)` which
   is not 100 % stable and takes lot of time for execution. Hence we
   don't want to plug our tests along with application build.

Also We do not have access to the source code of the application as well.

2. Here is our requirement We need to set up Code Coverage tool in our
   Application build and once it build and deployed successfully(This
   happens in the cloud).Then We get downloadable link to install the
   Product/Application on one of our execution VM. After Installation
   of application/Product we run our automation tests on VM and once
   it completes the execution we need to get the Report on  Code
   Coverage for our Automation tests.

---

I certainly know that my requirement little bit complex..But just trying to see how we can collect code coverage report for our tests.

Any ideas/suggestions on above requirement would be very handy/Helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get jacoco report from running acceptance test on real application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300162/get-jacoco-report-from-running-acceptance-test-on-real-application)